# Generic unique pointers

Tags: c++

Below is my sample code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std::placeholders;

template <typename recvtype, typename responsetype>
void myfunc(std::unique_ptr<recvtype> input, std::function<void(std::unique_ptr<responsetype>)> callback)
{
        auto msg = std::make_unique<responsetype>();
        callback(std::move(msg));
    return;
}

class Ret
{
public:
Ret(){}
void BRet(std::unique_ptr<Ret> r)
{
std::cout << "Called Me!!!" << std::endl << std::fflush;
}

};

class In
{
public:
In(){}
};

void test(std::unique_ptr<In> input, std::function<void(std::unique_ptr<Ret>)> callback)
{
myfunc<In , Ret>(std::move(input), callback);
}

int main()
{
std::unique_ptr<In> a = std::make_unique<In>();
Ret r1;
std::function<void(std::unique_ptr<Ret>)> f = std::bind(&Ret::BRet, &r1, _1);
test(std::move(a),f);
}
```

When I compile and execute the code I get below output:

```
$ c++ --std=c++14 -g try17.cpp

MINGW64 /c/test
$ ./a.exe
Called Me!!!
1
MINGW64 /c/test
$
```

I am not sure from where the **'1'** getting printed on console and how can I make **test** to accept generic unique pointers - I mean test method can now be called for any type instead of **'In and Ret'** types?

Answer (score 6):

The `1` comes from this line:

```
std::cout << "Called Me!!!" << std::endl << std::fflush;
```

Note that at the end you use `std::fflush`. That's not the [`std::flush`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush) manipulator but the [`std::fflush`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fflush) function.

The function decays to a boolean value that is always true, which is why you get the `1` printed.

Note that using `std::flush` (the manipulator) is not needed, as [`std::endl`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) will flush the stream. Also note that `std::endl` usually isn't needed either, unless you explicitly want to flush the stream. Printing a plain newline is usually enough:

```
std::cout << "Called Me!!!\n";
```

Comment: Thanks that solves my first part of the question - please let me know how can I make the test method to accept generic unique pointers - that means I can now pass any types to the method

Comment: @Programmer You should probably separate it into its own question. Having two unrelated questions like this really makes your question to broad. One question per question please.

Comment: Sorry for the same but I did requested that info in my question body itself initially - should I create a new post now?